# How do I group together string rows with partial matching strings and then sum them together?

Tags: r, sum, contains, matching, group

| Artist | Points |
| --- | --- |
| Notorious BIG | 34 |
| Notorious BIG feat. blah blah | 42 |
| 2pac | 20 |
| Dr.Dre feat. 2pac | 30 |

I would like to group and sum by Artist for a table to look like so:

| Artist | Points |
| --- | --- |
| Notorious BIG | 76 |
| 2pac | 50 |

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to approach this is to know which are the ones you want to combine since problem occurs when rows have multiple commonalities i.e.

| Artist | Points |
| --- | --- |
| 2pac | 34 |
| Dr. Dre feat. 2pac | 100 |
| Dr. Dre | 80 |

You can specify the names of the rows you want to combine using the base R `grepl` function, and the `dplyr` functions, `case_when` and `summarise`.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(Artist = c("Notorious BIG", "Notorious BIG feat. blah blah", "2pac", "Dr.Dre feat. 2pac"),
             Points = c(34, 42, 20, 30))
df <- df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Artist = case_when(
    grepl("2pac", Artist) ~ "2pac",
    grepl("Notorious BIG", Artist) ~ "Notorious BIG"),
                Artist = factor(Artist)) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(Artist) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(Points = sum(Points)) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup()
```